# Text is placed on the screen but it scroll

Tags: android, flutter

android studio 3.6

I need to scroll text only if text does not fit the screen. So if text is placed on the screen it MUST NOT scroll.

snippet:

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: new Column(
                        children: [
                          new Text("column_1", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow)),
                          new Text("column_2", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue)),
                          new Text("column_3", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.black12))])))));
  }
}
```

result

[image]

but I can scroll. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is scrolling as your column sits inside a `singleChildScrollView()` which enables scrolling by default.

As our container was using a `MediaQuery` to set its height, the `singleChildScrollView()` has no vertical space to expand into and thus resulted in the scrolling behaviour.

Instead we should wrap our `singleChildScrollView()` inside a container and then perform the `MediaQuery` on that container instead.

Please see the below code:

```
 return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(              
              child: new Column(
                children: [
                  new Text(
                    "column_1",
                    style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow),
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "column_2",
                    style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "column_3",
                    style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.black12),
                  ),                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: But if text does not fit the screen then it not scroll. But must scroll in this case

Comment: Sorry, i misread your question, i have edited my answer accordingly and you should now be able to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I add my answer. My solution has fewer lines of code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Column(children: [
          new Container(height: 64.0, color: Colors.blue),
          new Container(
              height: Constants.CARD_VIEW_HEIGHT, color: Colors.yellow),
          new Container(height: 356.0, color: Colors.red)
        ]))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ListView is the simplest answer I think;

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: new Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: new ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      Center(child: new Text("column_1", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow))),
                      Center(child: new Text("column_2", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue))),
                      Center(child: new Text("column_3", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.black12)))]))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use height and width on the ScrollView itself, rather than Column. The Column is taking more space on screen, causing it to scroll.